# Marshal unmanaged structure with enum member to c#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have an `unmanaged C++ code` and I want to convert it to `managed C# code`, the unmanaged code is shown below, I've searched but I did not find my answer...I want to know the right way for marshaling the below code, I am not sure how to marshal an enum and then reference it in an structure..the `MMTPConxNack` structure is a member of a union inside another structure.
the hierarchy is shown below:

```
typedef enum
{
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_NoAnswer=-2,            
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_SendError=-1,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_Ok=0,                  
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidMember,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_HubNotReady,           
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_UnknownMember,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_LastCnxTooRecent,       
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidVersion,        
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidOptions,       
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_TooManyCnx             
} MMTPCnxNckRsn;

typedef struct
{
    MMTPCnxNckRsn Reason;
} MMTPConxNack;


typedef struct
{
    long Length;
    short Type;
    union
    {
        MMTPConxReq ConxReq;
        MMTPConxAck ConxAck;
        MMTPConxNack ConxNack; // the structure with an enum inside
        MMTPErrInd ErrInd;      
    } Data;  
} MMTPMsg;
```

actually I want to marshal the `MMTPConxNack` structure..and I use FieldOffset to define the size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to see a bit more code, what is this FieldOffset of which you speak? Are you actually porting the code shown to C# and its marshalling over a network or do you want to marshal an object created with this code to a new piece of code written with the equivalent in c#?

Comment: @norlesh , above code is unmanaged c++ code...I want to marshal `MMTPConxNack` structure..when I want to marshal it I am not sure what is the right way because it has an enum member and it is inside a union.and because the union shared the memory among its members setting the size of each member is important as I know.

Comment: Its being marshalled from where to where?

Comment: I can not understand why this is important??..there is an unmanaged win32 dll and I want to call its methods, so 
I use marshaling..but the functions in dll receive messages on the network.

Comment: the reason I was asking is because marshalling can relate to passing messages between, processes, over networks, and in your case as we have established now - between win32 and .Net

Comment: @norlesh, Yeah..between .net and win32

Comment: Thanks, can't give you the verbatim answer - but the article I linked to in the answer should give you everything you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum looks like this:

```
public enum MMTPCnxNckRsn {
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_NoAnswer = -2, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_SendError = -1, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_Ok = 0, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidMember,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_HubNotReady,           
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_UnknownMember,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_LastCnxTooRecent,       
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidVersion,        
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidOptions,       
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_TooManyCnx             
}
```

The containing struct is:

```
public struct MMTPConxNack {
    public MMTPCnxNckRsn Reason; 
}
```

The union is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct MMTPMsgDataUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MMTPConxReq ConxReq;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MMTPConxAck ConxAck;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MMTPConxNack ConxNack;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MMTPErrInd ErrInd;
}
```

This is the tricky part. You use `LayoutKind.Explicit` and `FieldOffset` to specify that all the members of the C++ union is overlayed on each other. Obviously you need to have definitions for the other 3 types contained in this union, definitions that we cannot see in the C++ code in the question. I presume you already know how to define those.

Once you have the union declared, the final structure is simple:

```
public struct MMTPMMsg
{
    public int Length;
    public short Type;
    public MMTPMsgDataUnion Data;
}
```

Comment: the size of `MMTPMsgDataUnion` is not important? and all its members get the `[FieldOffset(0)]` (Zero)??

Comment: The above code matches that in the question. The size matches. Do you think it does not?

Comment: @Paridokht do you still need help?

Comment: Yes...Could you please tell me what is the size of `enum` in bytes?? I know may be my question is not clear enough..sorry..but assume that there is another member after union(`MMTPMsgDataUnion`),so I have to know the size of union which contains an `enum` to set the `fieldoffset` for the member which is after `MMTPMsgDataUnion`...the main problem is to know the size of `enum` in bytes which has the unsigned int.

Comment: An enum is just an int so on Windows it is four bytes. What are you going to do with that information? Do you think my answer is not accurate?

Comment: OK..I think your answer is accurate within my question..I think my question is not good ! ... I 've just ask another question..it would be so great if you look at that. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944585/enum-size-in-bytes

Answer (score 1):

You need a C# enum and struct to match the native ones:

```
public enum MMTPCnxNckRsn
{
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_NoAnswer,            
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_SendError,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_Ok,                  
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidMember,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_HubNotReady,           
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_UnknownMember,         
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_LastCnxTooRecent,       
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidVersion,        
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidOptions,       
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_TooManyCnx             
}

public struct MMTPConxNack
{
    public readonly MMTPCnxNckRsn Reason;
}
```

And you marshal it like this:

```
var managedItem = (MMTPConxNack)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer,typeof(MMTPConxNack));
```

Comment: you mean just define a c# enum and then in my `MMTPConxNack` structure set the `Reason` member which is an enum type to int type?

Comment: You will eventually need a C# enum with the same values if you want to use it in the C# code. The question is how you transfer the c++ struct to a .net struct. you need to define one which looks the same (i.e one field) and use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`

Comment: Could you please give me an example?? I know I should have an c# enum and I've already defined it.

Comment: Thank you..I will test your answer..but I am afraid because it is inside a union it wont work properly, if it works fine i will mark it as an answer :)

Comment: @I3arnon What about the union? And why do you need `PtrToStructure`?

Comment: The question's title and text seemed to me more oriented on the enum, not the union. So I saw your solution to it, and had nothing to add to it.