# Enum Size in Bytes

Tags: c#, pinvoke

What is the size of the enum below in bytes?

```
public enum MMTPCnxNckRsn 
{
    MMTPCnxNckRsnNoAnswer = -2, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnSendError = -1, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnOk = 0, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnInvalidMember = 1, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnHubNotReady = 2, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnUnknownMember = 3, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnLastCnxTooRecent = 4, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnInvalidVersion = 5, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnInvalidOptions = 6, 
    MMTPCnxNckRsnTooManyCnx = 7 
};
```

I've used the code below to find it but I think it is not enough. It is a string array with 10 elements. Should I count the chars in each element, assume each char to be 1 byte, and add all bytes of elements? What about unsigned numbers?

```
var size = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MMTPCnxNckRsn)).Length;
var arr = Enum.GetNames(typeof (MMTPCnxNckRsn));
```

I'm not sure if it is important to mention that I am in the middle of `marshaling` a native Win32 code to C#, and it is CRUCIAL to find the size of the enum for managing addresses in memory.

Comment: Can I ask why you feel the need to know the size of an enum value? Are you experiencing specific problems? Is it just down to a mis-think over how enums are stored (i.e. not as strings or arrays)?

Comment: @David Heffernan of course you can, in unmanaged code there is a structure(say s1), s1 has some members including a union(this union has an enum type member), I've used the `explicit layout kind` for marshaling s1 (to be more explicit and avoiding further problems of memory management!)..so I want to know the size of enum to obtain the size of union  and then set the offset(address) of members which comes after this union in s1. I used this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66243/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-3-Marshaling-Compound-Ty .. Real World example part, first example.

Comment: Don't use explicit. Let the compiler lay it out. It will get it right. Only time you use explicit is for FieldOffset(0) in a union. My answer to your other question shows how.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I think I have to use explicit because the code that I should marshal is too complicated..there are lots of structures which contain lots of unions, these unions again contain structures  with reference-type members and value-type members!!!!..and I've got error message!!!!..it is not that simple as is in my questions.

Comment: Explicit won't help. You just need to get the structs right.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) says:

> The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int.

Therefore, your data type will have the size of 4 bytes, which is the size of an int.
 You can confirm this by using the following command:

```
Marshal.SizeOf(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(MMTPCnxNckRsn)));
```

Whilst you refer to the enum values in source code using a name, they are represented in the code that runs on the machine as integer values. So your comment about string arrays is quite wide of the mark.

I also think you are over-thinking the issue of size. Looking at your other recent question, you seem to be translating a C++ structure to C# for pinvoke. Well, the C# enum will map straight onto the C++ enum. The pinvoke marshaller will look after the sizes and lay them out for you. You do not need to handle that explicitly.

Comment: In newer .NET versions (I believe since .NET Core 1), you can use Unsafe.SizeOf<MMTPCnxNckRsn>().  It's cleaner and should perform much faster.