# how is memory allocated to enumerated data type in c#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

where are enumerated data types stored in the memory. what actually happens inside the compiler when i declare an enumerated data type.

here is the sample program

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WeekDays wd = new WeekDays();
        Console.WriteLine(wd.Friday);
        Console.WriteLine((int)wd.Friday);
    }
}

public enum WeekDays
{
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday = 1,
    Wednesday = 2,
    Thursday = 3,
    Friday = 4,
    Saturday = 5,
    Sunday = 6
}
```

Can we use instances created to Enum. The Compiler is not allowing me to access variables of the Class
it throws this error "Static member `WeekDays.Friday' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enums are not allocated in memory - they exist only on compilation stage. They only exist to tell compiler what value is Tuesday in ur example. When code runs - there is no enums there anymore.

It does same thing as below

```
#define Monday 0;
#define Tuesday 1;
.
.
.
.
#define Sunday 6;
```

But we prefer enums than define because easier to support and read the code with enums then with #defines.

u can get clarity of enum size by this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944766/10126070)

Answer (score 1):

Enumerations have the memory Profile of compile time Constants. By default integer constants, but other integer types can be used as well. There may be some additional stuff for reflection, but I am unsure that amounts to much in the big picture.

Variables that take a Enumeration value, accordingly have the memory profile of the underlying type. Casting a Enum to a Integer can usually be done implicitly as well, but not the other way around.

Comment: do enumerated data types get stored in the stack or the heap? can you diagrammatically represent its storage.

Comment: @GodugunuriPavanKrishna: The stack is a implementation detail. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

Comment: As you might be looking for extremes of speed, the Performance rant might also be in order: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ But in general you hit top performance hte moment you picked enumerations. How much faster then integer comparision can you get?